# How to download a pdf saved in a mysql database as a MEDIUMBLOB data using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have saved a pdf file in a mysql database as a MEDIUMBLOB file. I used the following code to download it. The file that downloads is the same size and file type as the original file, but it won't open properly. What could be the problem & how to fix it?

```
$emp_no=55;
$DOB="2014-09-03";

$query="SELECT file_name, file_type, file_size, file_data FROM document WHERE emp_no=$emp_no AND DOB='$DOB'";
$retval=mysqli_query($non,$query);

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($retval,MYSQL_ASSOC);
$file_name=$row['file_name'];
$file_type=$row['file_type'];
$file_size=$row['file_size'];
$file_data=$row['file_data'];

header("Content-length: $file_size");
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
echo $file_data;
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Can you post an original pdf and a downloaded pdf somewhere so they may be compared byte-by-byte to locate the problem? It could something as simple as a prepended space character on the downloaded file.

Comment: You can find the two pdf files here :  https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bz9KLJr9b_3JNXRQaHBqXzZZMjg&usp=sharing

Comment: I still couldn't find the reason for this error. If anyone can think of a reason please do tell.

Comment: Comparing the 2 files you have posted, you can notice that the downloaded differs from the original in head and footer. The first lines of the files seems to be html, maybe the problem was the saving process on the db.

Comment: To be precise, if you compare the 2 files, the dowloaded file has the wrong html head 2630 bytes long, and misses the 2630 byte footer of the original file. So I repeat, the problem is in the saving procedure.

Comment: @Binujaya Can you please add saving code?

Comment: To clear up any HTML errors that can cause download corruption, you can enable output buffering with ob_start() and then do ob_end_clean() just before echoing the binary data.  You can also try to echo the binary data but change the headers to Content-type: text/plain to see what you're dumping out in the browser.  A combination of these 2 techniques should give a definitive answer if the corruption is saved into the binary column or not.  (you could also just view the blob column in some kind of GUI tool, or select substr( blobcol, 0, 30) to see the start of the data)

Answer (score 1):

Open your downloaded.pdf in Notepad, you'll see there's PHP Error Notices at the top of the file, these will corrupt any downloaded file.

Some solutions:

- Fix them ;-)
- Turn off reporting of E_NOTICE Errors via `error_reporting(E_ERROR);` in the first line of your PHP Code
- Build your own [custom error reporting mechanics](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and turn off the printing of errors to browser via `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` so they can't mess with downloaded files

You can either fix these, or add a

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final working solution:

```js
<?php
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

//Get id from form (POST)
$order = $_POST['Order'];

//Set connection
$servername = "mysql.yourserver.com";
$username = "yourusername";
$password = "yourpassword";
$dbname = "yourdatabasename";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Error: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

//Retrieve data from db
$result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id='.$order);

//Set rows to variables
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $size = $row["size"];
  $type = $row["type"];
  $filename = $row["filename"];
  $content = $row["content"];
}

//Get file
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
echo $content;

//End connection
$conn->close();
?>
```